# Increasing cookie max length in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

Google Chrome browser (v109) seems to enforce a maximum length for cookies set using JavaScript `document.cookie`.
Is it possible to increase the cap with manual browser configuration by the user?

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 1012 cookie size must not be limited by user agent.

Chrome supports HTML5 **localStorage** that allows you to use a dictionary style look up. You can use this to store larger amounts of data instead of passing them back and forth using cookies.

If you must use cookies, You can't change the cookie size but you can use several cookies and span your data across them, keeping one cookie as a pointer to other cookies so you know what they're called, how many there are, etc (like a partition table on a harddisk).